# Setting for PDO Default Port in php.ini?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, port

Is it possible to change the default port for PDO?

I already changed `mysqli.default_port` and `mysql.default_port` in my php.ini.
PDO ignores this changes to the default port but i couldn't find any setting for PDO. If i specify the port in the PDO constructor everything works fine. But i'm searching for a default setting.
Database ip is not localhost but `192.168.178.25` so this shouldn't be the common problem

Comment: I'd say [it isn't possible](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.configuration)...

Comment: Just use it like this `new PDO('mysql:host=192.168.178.25;port=YOURPORT;dbname=test', $user, $pass);`

Comment: @wayneOS just read my question. I'm familar with this.